# how to read words from text file in VC#

Tags: file, text, dictionary, cpu-word, words

I want to read a text file and cut the words from each other ,for example this is my text file :

asd 
asdc
asf
gas
asdf

Now i want to read "asd" ,then "asdc" ,then "asf" ...
How could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
List<string> words = new List<string>();
string line;
char[] sep = new char[] { ' ', '\t' };

try
{
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        words.AddRange(line.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));  
    }
    file.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

This code read text file line by line and separate each line into words (by space and tabs). You have to handle the exceptions by yourself.

Comment: Sorry but I'm newbie , could you give me more help?<br> How can i print them in a listbox?

Comment: You only need to replace the `C:\\test.txt` by you path to the file, the result will be contained in the `words` variable as a list of string :).

Answer (score 0):

With StreamReader's ReadLine you can read line for line like this:

using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{

```
public static void Main() 
{

    try 
    {

        // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
        // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
        {
            String line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // Let the user know what went wrong.
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

}